How to limit the width of select box without specifying pixels
I want to prevent empty select boxes with ultra-wide options from expanding to the width of the widest option. The only solutions I've found involve setting max-width to a certain number of px. I'm learning CSS and trying to practice responsive design, so I want to avoid that.
The following illustrates the problem. Note that the Venue select box, even when empty, is very wide. I would like for it to remain the exact width (3fr) I specified. When displaying the option list it should either truncate with ellipses, or wrap to multiple lines.
And I'd welcome any suggestions for different ways to accomplish this. I'm a novice at HTML/CSS.


 * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* On smaller screens, increase text size */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      .input {font-size: 120%}
      .label {font-size: 120%}
      .checkbox {font-size: 120%}
  }
  .power-h1 {
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      text-align: center;
  }
  .search-form-container {
      max-width: 640px;
  }
  .labeled-input-container {
  }
  .labeled-input {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  }
  .label {
      align-self: center;
  }
  .input {
      // ?
  }
  select {
      // ?
  }
  option {
      // ?
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="search-form-container">
    <h1 class="power-h1">Power Search</h1>
    <div class="labeled-input-container">
      <!-- band search -->
      <div class="labeled-input">
        <label class="label" for="band">Band</label>
        <select class="input" id="band" name="band">
          <option></option>
          <option>The Archies</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- venue search -->
      <div class="labeled-input">
        <label class="label" for="venue">Venue</label>
        <select class="input" id="venue" name="venue">
          <option></option>
          <option>A very absurdly bigly widely huge name for a
          venue, made even bigger.</option>
        </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




Use overflow: hidden; to prevent <select> larger than expected.
Add ... by text-overflow: ellipsis;.
select {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* On smaller screens, increase text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .input {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
  .label {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
  .checkbox {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
}

.power-h1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-form-container {
  max-width: 640px;
}

.labeled-input {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.label {
  align-self: center;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
<div class="search-form-container">
  <h1 class="power-h1">Power Search</h1>
  <div class="labeled-input-container">
    <!-- band search -->
    <div class="labeled-input">
      <label class="label" for="band">Band</label>
      <select class="input" id="band" name="band">
        <option></option>
        <option>The Archies</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <!-- venue search -->
    <div class="labeled-input">
      <label class="label" for="venue">Venue</label>
      <select class="input" id="venue" name="venue">
        <option></option>
        <option>A very absurdly bigly widely huge name for a venue, made even bigger.</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Running the code snippet in Chrome/Mac, the Venue select box is still very wide.

Using developer tools in Chrome I find the following:
User agent stylesheet:
select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

I'm guessing this is overriding the select { overflow: hidden} ...?

In chrome use select{width:100%;} can avoid the issue.
